# Why does tkinter say that I have slaves managed by a grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a tkinter GUI with multiple classes to manage the code. However, when I try to use `pack()` on a `Label`, it gives an error that there is already a slave managed by `grid`. The `Label` is inside a `tk.Frame`, and the `tk.Frame` is using `grid()` in the main window, so I do not understand why the `pack()` is not working.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
class TextIO(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        inputLabel = ttk.Label(parent, text = "Input:")
        inputLabel.pack(side = "top")
        inputString = tk.Text(parent)
        inputString.pack(side = "top")

        outputLabel = ttk.Label(parent, text = "Output:")
        outputLabel.pack(side = "bottom")
        output = tk.Text(parent)
        output.insert("0.0", "Type -1 in shift if you want all shifts when decrypting")
        output.pack(side = "bottom")


class ButtonBox(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        shiftLabel = ttk.Label(parent, text = "Shift:")
        shiftLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        amountShift = ttk.Entry(parent, width = 5)
        amountShift.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        encryptButton = ttk.Button(parent, text = "Encrypt", width = 20)
        encryptButton.config(command = lambda: respondToUser('E'))
        encryptButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

        decryptButton = ttk.Button(parent, text = "Decrypt", width = 20)
        decryptButton.config(command = lambda: respondToUser('D'))
        decryptButton.grid(row = 0, column = 3)


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.UserIO = TextIO(self)
        self.UserIO.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.Buttons = ButtonBox(self)
        self.Buttons.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

root = tk.Tk()
MainWindow(root).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Code Projects/Caesar Cipher.py", line 122, in <module>
    MainWindow(root).pack()
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Code Projects/Caesar Cipher.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.UserIO.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2060, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .1960274768 which already has slaves managed by pack
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `TextIO`, because the parent of its children widgets is `TextIO` itself<sup>[1]</sup>, not its `parent`, so you should correct:

```
inputLabel = ttk.Label(parent, text = "Input:")
```

with

```
inputLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Input:")
```

Same thing for `inputString`, `outputLabel` and `output`.

<sup>I mean, the current *instance* of a `TextIO` object.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In `TextIO` you're using `parent` (which is already managed by `grid`) and not `self` as the parent for the buttons. Hence the error.

But perhaps equally important:

Mixing the `grid` and `pack` geometry managers is not a good idea. These work fundamentally different and there can also be some serious edge-cases when mixing `grid` and `pack` in the same window. TK can do some strange things trying to negotiate the layout, causing strange layouts, infinite loops, etc. You really don't want to do it.

The most sane case, in my personal opinion, is to just always use `grid`. It's the easiest and most flexible. `pack` is sometimes nice to quickly get started, but there are some things that can be difficult to do later on.